# Deleting rows in Postgres table using ctid

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

We have a table with nearly 2 billion events recorded. As per our data model, each event is uniquely identified with 4 columns combined primary key. Excluding the primary key, there are 5 B-tree indexes each on single different columns. So totally 6 B-tree indexes.

The events recorded span for years and now we need to remove the data older than 1 year.

We have a `time` column with long values recorded for each event. And we use the following query,

`delete from events where ctid = any ( array (select ctid from events where time < 1517423400000 limit 10000) )`

Does the indices gets updated?

During testing, it didn't.

After insertion,

`total_table_size - 27893760
table_size - 7659520
index_size - 20209664`

After deletion,

`total_table_size - 20226048
table_size - 0
index_size - 20209664`

Comment: A DELETE statement **will** update the indexes. Did you run a `vacuum full` to reclaim the freed space?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No. There are frequent concurrent inserts in this table. How much time will it take to complete a Vaccum full on a table with 2 billion events, as it takes an exclusive lock ? Does VACUUM FULL necessary or VACUUM enough ?

Comment: If you want to efficiently clean out old data, you should consider [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)  then cleaning out the data gets as fast as dropping a table. (You would need to store the "time" as a proper `timestamp` though)

Answer (score 0):

Reindex can be done

```
Command:     REINDEX
Description: rebuild indexes
Syntax:
REINDEX { INDEX | TABLE | DATABASE | SYSTEM } name [ FORCE ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) method is the good solution.

**What we had:**
Postgres version 9.4.
`1 table` with `2 billion` rows with `21 columns` (all `bigint`) and `5 columns` combined primary key and `5` individual column indices with date spanning 2 years.

It looks similar to time-series data with a `time` column containing UNIX timestamp except that its analytics project, so time is not at an ordered increase. The table was insert and select only (most select queries use aggregate functions).

**What we need:** Our data span is 6 months and need to remove the old data.

**What we did** (with less knowledge on Postgres internals):
Delete rows at 10000 batch rate.

At inital, the delete was so fast taking `ms`, as the bloat increased each batch delete increased to nearly `10s`. Then `autovacuum` got triggered and it ran for almost `3 months`. The insert rate was high and each batch delete has increased the WAL size too. Poor stats in the table made the current queries so slow that they ran for minutes and hours.

So we decided to go for Partitioning. Using Table Inheritance in 9.4, we implemented it.

**Note:** Postgres has [Declarative Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) from version 10, which handles most manual work needed in partitioning using Table Inheritance.

Please go through the [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-partitioning.html) as they have clear explanation.

Simplified and how we implemented it:

1. Create parent table
2. Create child table inheriting it with check constraints. (We had monthly partitions and created using schedular)
3. Indexes are need to be created separately for each child table
4. To drop old data, just drop the table, so vacuum is not needed and will be instant.
5. Make sure to have the postgres property `constraint_exclusion` to `partition`.
6. `VACUUM ANALYZE` the old partition after started inserting in the new partition. (In our case, it helped the query planner to use Index-Only scan instead of Seq. scan)
7. Using Triggers as mentioned in the docs may make the inserts slower, so we deviated from it, as we partitioned based on `time` column, we calculated the table name at application level based on `time` value before every insert and it didn't affect the insert rate for us.

Also read other caveats mentioned there.